# regexp get filename from url

Tags: php, regex

url: http://blabla.bl/blabla/ss/sd/filename
How to get a filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [earcar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131815/earcar)'s suggestion (basename) to get the filename.

BUT, if we're starting with a URL and the filename includes a query string, use [Mauris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126039/mauris)'s suggestion as well.

The query string will start with ? (*that's how we know it's not part of the filename*) and we can use

```
explode('?', basename($url));
```

This is summed up by [the online PHP manual for basename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php#58372)

Answer (score 5):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

It works even on urls.

Answer (score 2):

Given an arbitrary URL, I think you should use [basename()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) together with [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). Something like this:

```
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$path = $parsed_url['path'];
$filename = basename($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works, but last thing, sometimes basename is aaaa_somewhat. How to delete _somewhat?

Comment: $behind_underscore = array_pop(explode('_',basename($url)));
unlink($behind_underscore);